# WordPress - Wrong URL Structure when post are created under Category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created articles under category `Our News & Events` > `Latest News`. The URL sturture is `http://localhost/example/our-news-events/latest-news/` but when I click on any of the post, the URL changes to `http://localhost/example/news-5/.

How can I structure the URL so that is follows its hierarchy e.g. `http://localhost/example/our-news-events/latest-news/news-5/`

1. I have already set `Permalink Settings` to `Post name`
2. Already cleared the WordPress cache, changed theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Under `Permalink Settings`, I have to change the option to custom structure and `/%category%/%postname%/` in the field